# Problem in deploying to IBM bluemix java/spring service

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud

I am deploying a java spring boot application as a deployable war into an IBM bluemix environment via jenkins.  I am able to build and run the service in my local environment.  During the build pipeline, I am getting this.  Any ideas?

```
Staging app and tracing logs...
   Downloading liberty-for-java...
   Downloaded liberty-for-java
   Cell 26776ec2-6370-4ef1-8987-54aa61d8fe79 creating container for instance 1cc919a5-8e81-4c91-aa64-9b7274d7715d
   Cell 26776ec2-6370-4ef1-8987-54aa61d8fe79 successfully created container for instance 1cc919a5-8e81-4c91-aa64-9b7274d7715d
   Downloading app package...
   Downloaded app package (2.6K)
   -----> Liberty Buildpack Version: v3.44-20200430-1451
   E, [2021-02-22T22:06:45.730075 #22] ERROR -- /tmp/buildpacks/fb2e823ce09e8909e2afd757be3d1971/lib/liberty_buildpack/buildpack.rb:50:in `rescue in drive_buildpack_with_logger': Compile failed with exception #<RuntimeError: No supported application type was detected>
   No supported application type was detected
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to compile droplet: exit status 1
   Exit status 223
   Cell 26776ec2-6370-4ef1-8987-54aa61d8fe79 stopping instance 1cc919a5-8e81-4c91-aa64-9b7274d7715d
   Cell 26776ec2-6370-4ef1-8987-54aa61d8fe79 destroying container for instance 1cc919a5-8e81-4c91-aa64-9b7274d7715d
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED
```

Comment: What is "bluemix"...? IBM Cloud? Cloud Foundry, Cloud Functions, Code Engine, Kubernetes, VM, ...? Please addmore details about what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error basically means the buildpack did not find an artifact it recognizes as an app it supports.  The liberty buildpack recognizes wars, jars, liberty server directories and packaged servers.

The buildpack will look for an artifact in the current directory or in the directory specified with the `-p` CLI flag or `path` in the manifest.

Ensure your artifact exists where the buildpack can find it.

Comment: It was related to not finding the correct artifact, once we corrected that it worked!